# ListView com JSON + PHP

Tags: php, java, android, json, android-studio

Quero que apareça numa `ListView` todas as informações de um select que dei. Consigo fazer apenas com o txt aparecendo uma informação:

```
public void sendjsonrequest() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, HOST, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {

                contrato = response.getString("contrato");
                tipo = response.getString("tipo");
                horario = response.getString("horario");


                //txtContrato.setText(contrato);
                //txtTipo.setText(tipo);
                //txtHorario.setText(horario);
            } catch (
                    JSONException e)

            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```

Estou com dúvida de como inserir essas informações em um `ListView`.

```
contrato = response.getString("contrato");
tipo = response.getString("tipo");
horario = response.getString("horario");
```

Comment: Poderia esclarecer melhor onde o PHP entra nessa história e qual a relação dele com o problema?

Comment: Faço uma conexão do Json com o PHP onde no servidor tem um arquivo PHP com o SELECT. Minha duvida e como pegar as String "contrato, tipo e horário" e colocar numa ListView para aparecer mais de 1 dado na tela. Atualmente estou usando uma TextView para mostrar o resultado mas aparece so 1.

Comment: a tag php não faz sentido pra essa pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aparecer esses três dados, crie um objeto e preencha ele com esse retorno do seu código php.

```
public class MeuObjeto {
    private String Contrato, Tipo, Horario;
}
```

A seguir, crie uma lista com esses objetos; utilize o conceito de [Recyclerview](https://medium.com/android-dev-br/listas-com-recyclerview-d3f41e0d653c) pra criar um `listview` com esses dados.

Comment: Obrigado funcionou !

Comment: Pode marcar como resposta :)